# Rails different behavior between :url vs url_for({:controller:, :action})

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How come when I have a link in my view file like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), :url => new_foo_path, :class => "banner-image" %>
```

The resulting markup produces an invalid anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="/home/index?class=banner-image&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ffoo%2Fnew"><img alt="foo" src="/assets/foo.png"></a>
```

But if I do this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), url_for({:controller => "foo", :action => "new"}), :class => "banner-image" %>
```

It works perfectly - which produces this:

```
<a href="/foo/new" class="banner-image"><img alt="foo" src="/assets/foo.png"></a>
```

My routes.rb contains this line for foo:

```
resources :foo, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: If i recall you don't need to pass the :url param in your first example.
`<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), new_foo_path, :class => "banner-image" %>` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/797fcdf738a2a2772544731027d4fc5ca9d358bc/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L174

This happens because in the first form you're essentially passing the `url` & `class` in the `options` hash that the method accepts. In other words you're doing this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), { :url => new_foo_path, :class => "banner-image" } %>
```

Passing additional key-values in the `options` hash will append them as URL params in the final query string, thus the resulting markup in your first snippet.

But what you want to actually do is:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), { :url => new_foo_path }, { :class => "banner-image" } %>
```

which will pass the first hash as the `options` hash and the second as the `html_options` hash.

However as other have mentioned, you can just do:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), new_foo_path, :class => "banner-image" %>
```

which will pass the `new_foo_path` as the value in `:url` and `{ :class => 'banner-image' }` as the `html_options` hash.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `new_foo_path` directly in `link_to`. No need to add `:url =>` for it.

```
<%= link_to your-text-or-image-tag, your-path %>
```

For more please have a look on the link http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to.